# Is $\mathbb{D} = [-1,1]^3$ a compact manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds-with-boundary, retraction

Today I read about a generalization of the no-retraction theorem [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Retraction_Theorem) which states the following:

> Then there is no smooth mapping $f:M\to \partial M$ such that the restriction $f_{|\partial M}: \partial M \to \partial $ is the identity, where $M$ is a compact manifold with boundary $\partial M$ and $f_{|\partial M}$ denotes the restriction of the function $f$ to the boundary of the manifold $M.$

I know this theorem to be true for balls in $\mathbb{R}^n,$, however, the problem I am working on requires me to apply this theorem on a cube domain $\mathbb{D} = [-1,1]^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ So my question is whether the domain $\mathbb{D}$ is a compact manifold? Any hints/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by a manifold.

Comment: I refer to the usual definition of a manifold, but I am not sure if I understand your comment. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: There is no such a thing as the "usual" definition. One definition is for **topological** manifolds, another definition is for **smooth manifolds,** yet another definition would require a smooth submanifold of $R^n$ (it is the one which, I think, you are implcitly using).

Comment: In the current form the question is un-answerable. It is unclear what notion of a manifold you are using (smooth or topological), what proof of the non-retraction theorem do you know, etc. In view of the link, it is possible that you are asked to imitate the proof in the smooth category for manifolds and maps which are merely piecewise-smooth, like the boundary of the cube: If so, it is very much unclear from the question.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, a cube is homeomorphic to a closed ball in the usual metric, so anything topological that applies to the closed ball also applies to a cube.

Comment: +1 but there is some subtlety since the version of the no-retraction theorem the OP wants to use only denies the existence of a smooth map from the ball to its boundary which is the identity on the boundary; maybe there is an exotic continuous one.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{D}$ is a compact manifold with boundary. Once you know it is a manifold with boundary, it is quickly compact, by the Heine-Borel Theorem (because it is closed and bounded).

You can verify it is a manifold with boundary either by finding charts into $\mathbb{H}^3$ (which takes a little bit of effort at corners and edges) or by considering the map $f:\mathbb{D} \to \overline{B_1(0, 0, 0)},$

where $$f(x, y, z) = \frac{\max(|x|, |y|,|z|)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}(x, y, z)$$ if $(x, y, z)\ne (0, 0, 0),$ and $f(0, 0, 0) = 0.$

($\overline{B_1(0, 0, 0)}$ is the closed unit ball around the origin.)

Then, $f$ is diffeomorphic, and charts for $\mathbb{D}$ can be obtained from charts on $\overline{B_1(0, 0, 0)}$ using $f$. For instance, if $$\varphi: U\subset \overline{B_1(0, 0, 0)} \to \mathbb{H}^n$$ is a chart for $\overline{B_1(0, 0, 0)}$, $$\varphi\circ f: f^{-1}(U)\to \mathbb{H}^n$$ gives a chart for $\mathbb{D}.$

Comment: Why is $f$ a diffeomorphism? (I agree it is a homeomorphism but why is it smooth?)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of awkwardness since the theorem you want to use applies to smooth manifolds, and the restriction of the smooth structure from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the cube is not a smooth structure.

But it's also true if we forget differential topology and only worry about continuous maps: the boundary of the cube has non-trivial $H^2$, so the identity map from the boundary to itself can't factor through the cube, which has trivial $H^2$.